# CAD file really slows down Blender file

Tags: blend-files, memory-management, conversion

I've started a new file and imported a relatively simple CAD file (DXF, 32Mb). After converting all to meshes and separating into individual elements, it's now got to the point where the file is virtually unusable - and before I've even started modelling anything!

The Blend file is over 300Mb, it takes several seconds to select anything, and machine / file restarts don't have any impact. My machine is pretty high spec and doesn't have issues in other software.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this is what working with CAD files is like in Blender?

Comment: What is your object count and poly count? Blender doesn't perform well with high poly count nor large scenes. CAD files converted to meshes often have crazy poly count, and it doesn't help if you further more separate them in even more objects.

Comment: The scene is currently 70,500 objects but only 400 polys. So the DXF imported as a series of joined curves. I've gone through the mesh / separation process to enable me to separate the drawings by storey / elevation. Is it best to keep everything as Curves instead? (And somehow still separate them by storey?)

Comment: Update - splitting but keeping them as curves seems to make the file a lot happier. Thanks for the tip.